# Trying to find a pure python integer linear programming solver with inequalities

Tags: python, google-app-engine, linear-programming

I have a program written in App Engine (python) and I want to use an integer linear programming solver in it. All solvers I could find seems to be written partly in C, so I would imagine they won't work in App Engine.

Anyone knows of a pure python library that solves integer linear programming with inequalities?

I managed to find this http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/1252 but it seems that it doesn't deal with inequalities.

Comment: Have you tried the ones you've found? (could you link to them in your question?)

Comment: I just downloaded whatever I could find on stackoverflow / wikipedia and checked if they have c files. All of them did.

Comment: And those would be helpful links to include in your question (see [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)). My point was "you don't imagine they'd work in app engine", **I think they will**, did you try??

Comment: I have reason to believe they won't work (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Pure_Python), so I am not interested in investing the time in trying. If you think otherwise you are welcome to post an answer/comment and say why. Furthermore maybe it would be better to keep your general views about the culture of asking questions in meta/up and down votes.

Comment: I think that is more relevant to writing your own C extensions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do the trick: http://labix.org/python-constraint